# Openshot crashes when exporting video on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, video-editor, openshot

OpenShot (version 2.4.3) crashes when it is exporting a video (YouTube HD 720p 30fps). 
I installed it using apt and official repos.
This is the last part of the log file:

```
  export:INFO YouTube-HD
  export:INFO None
  export:INFO None
  export:INFO /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/profiles/atsc_1080p_2398
  export:INFO /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/profiles/atsc_1080p_2398
  export:INFO Low
  export:INFO Med
  export:INFO Valid framerate detected, sending to libopenshot: 23.976023976023978
  export:INFO /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/profiles/atsc_720p_30
  export:INFO /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/profiles/atsc_720p_30
  export:INFO Valid framerate detected, sending to libopenshot: 30.0
  export:INFO High
  export:INFO /home/lorenrookie/Escritorio/prueba.mp4
  logger:ERROR /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/main_window.py:2226: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  logger:ERROR   from gi.repository import Unity
```

main_window:INFO auto_save_project
 main_window:INFO Creating backup of project file: /home/lorenrookie/.openshot_qt/backup/backup.osp
 main_window:INFO auto_save_project

Any idea?

Comment: Openshot crashing unfortunately is not sounding very new to me. Of course, this is fatal if it happens while exporting. Try other versions (the app image, the Snap version). Else move to another videoeditor. KDEnlive is a lot more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I have tries the appimage an It works but it is much less efficient. Even less than the Windows version.